# Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have a lottery website and I'm getting results from a third-party XML into my Database, sometimes I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (// ) at position 0 (/): Unexpected character in /wp-content/themes/astra/functions.php:458

This is the lines of the issue in my code

```
            $zone=3600*0;
            $dat1e=gmdate("m/d/y H:i", time() + $zone); 
            $newDate = str_replace(' GMT','',$row['next_draw_date']);
            $vv = explode(' ',$newDate);
            $v1 = explode('/',$vv[0]);
            $end = $v1[1].'/'.$v1[0].'/'.$v1[2].' '.$vv[1];
            $dt = new DateTime($end);
            $date1 = $dt->format("D, d M Y H:i e");
```

Line 458 is:

```
            $dt = new DateTime($end);
```

Comment: is that code from the plugin itself? or yours? but anyways, if it's a valid date, im not sure why you would make string manipulations with it. just directly load it in the `DateTime` constructor

Comment: Read the error message... it says "Failed to parse time string (//)" - `row['next_draw_date']` was empty...